# Is it possible to pin an HTML element to the bottom of another?

Tags: html, css

A simple question for a simple problem. I'm working on a way to represent textual documents (such as book pages) with relatively simple HTML underlying them. Each HTML document can display many pages. The biggest problem I've run into is the footer. I want it to be simple, of course; perhaps just a `<FOOTER>` tag with plain text within it. However, I can't fathom how to force it to stay at the bottom of its page no matter how much text precedes it. **Is there any way to pin an HTML element to the bottom of another?**

Here's an example:

> http://prog.bhstudios.org/documents.htm

`position:relative` doesn't work because I don't know where the original position of the footer will be, other than "somewhere within its parent".

`position:absolute; bottom:0` doesn't work because that's relative to the viewing window's topleftmost position, not to the element's parent

`position:fixed; bottom:0` doesn't work because that takes it out of the flow and 'pins' it to the bottom of the viewing window, completely independent of the element's parent.

**I want something that works as one would expect `float:bottom` might work.**

Comment: In your html markup structure can't you just put footer element after the "page" element?

Comment: Try `position:absolute; top:100%;`

Comment: @rjml I could, but that's against this webpage's design philosophy, which is to make an HTML markup that's extremely easy for anyone to understand, even if they haven't used HTML before.

Comment: I don't think I understood then :)

Comment: @rjml perhaps a look at the accepted answer can help you understand :3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was just working on similar thing:

```
<div style="position: relative; height: 300px;">
    <h1>some content on top</h1>

    <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; background: #cccccc;">
        this is on bottom!
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The reason this works, and the OP's didn't, is because the parent div is positioned. Absolutely-positioned elements are positioned with respect to the first ancestor that's also positioned.

Comment: @isherwood! yeah! I was struggling all night long, and I've even memorized how to do this anytime :)